# how to split the json response using java having [{

Tags: java

Hi i am storing a json response as string. And unable to split my json response using the below text

```
{["id"
```

I tried using the java split  command as `split.("{["id"")`  but not able to split. Please help

Comment: Please clarify your question? Why are you unable? How exactly does your code look like, what do you expect to happen, what does happen instead? please provide the errorneous behavior and any error messages you get.

Comment: you shouldnt, intead you should parse that into a list/array

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the quotes in the string:

```
json.split("{[\"id\"");
```

Comment: We don't have enough information to analyze that error